# Operating JCalendar in a different time zone

Tags: java, swing, timezone, locale, jcalendar

I work on a legacy application that makes use of [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/). Is it possible to operate JCalendar in a different time zone? The internals of this package seem to assume the local time zone. Our application assumes GMT so we would like dates  and times to be handled and rendered in GMT by the `com.toedter.calendar.JTextFieldDateEditor` and `com.toedter.calendar.JSpinnerDateEditor` classes.

Answer (score 2):

For expedience, you might set the default `TimeZone` early in your program.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```